# How to create and populate a large database without blocking the calling activity

Tags: android, android-service

I am downloading a zip file from the internet, save it to the sd card, and unzip the file. My app reads the file line by line, where each line contains 96 column items. I add all items to `Contentvalues`, which inserts the values to a database.

I have done all these things in services and I'm starting this service in the `onCreate` method of my splash screen. But this service is not allowing the splash screen to start, it's taking too much time to populate the database.

Is there any way to do this in the background, without affecting the response of the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can start service in a separate thread or the whole process you are doing in service can be shifted to thread in service this will also help you in escaping from ANR problems.
obviously you can also use AsynkTask as mentioned in above example

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
public void run(){

/*Start service here or write the whole code that you are using in service 
and use this thread in service
*/

}};
```

Comment: I have tried with this thread.its not working.Getting same output.Its blocking the splash screen.

Comment: then use this thread in service. write the code which you are writing in service into this thread and use this thread in your service

Answer (score 5):

Sure! You can use AsynkTask, [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) you can find some documentation. 
Good luck!